# Merge two arrays based on a key and add new filed using mongo aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, aggregation

I need to write an aggregation to merge an array field into another array field using a condition.

Example:
Original doc:

```
[{
        "key": 1,
        "risks": [{
                "_id": "1234-risk1",
                "name": "risk1"
            }, {
                "_id": "9999-risk2",
                "name": "risk2"
            }
        ],
        "controls": [{
                "identifier": "P8.1.3",
                "links": [{
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "1234-risk1"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "identifier": "X8.1.3",
                "links": [{
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "1234-risk1"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }, 
            {
                "identifier": "Y8.1.3",
                "links": [{
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "9999-risk2"
                        }
                    }, {
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "identifier": "A1.2.9",
                "links": [{
                        "entity": {
                            "valueKey": "456"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The field risks.id (eg: 1234-risk1 and 9999-risk2) has related controls inside controls array field.
Also there are controls which does not match any risk.id match as well.

I need to create a new field riskControls to club risk + its corresponding controls if any, and then controls with out risks.

Expected:

```
[{
        "key": 1,
        "riskControls": [{
                "_id": "1234-risk1",
                "name": "risk1",
                "controls": [{
                        "identifier": "P8.1.3",
                        "links": [{
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "1234-risk1"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "456"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }, {
                        "identifier": "X8.1.3",
                        "links": [{
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "1234-risk1"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "456"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                "_id": "9999-risk2",
                "name": "risk2",
                "controls": [{
                        "identifier": "Y8.1.3",
                        "links": [{
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "9999-risk2"
                                }
                            }, {
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "456"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }, {
                //no risk details
                "controls": [{
                        "identifier": "A1.2.9",
                        "links": [{
                                "entity": {
                                    "valueKey": "456"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/MbRciOaKMHO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query

- find the controls-ids (the value-keys)
- find the rnc-ids (risks that dont have control ids)
- find the cnr-ids (>>)
- use this to make 3 arrays

  - rnc = risks that dont have control
  - cnr = controls that dont have risk
  - rc  = risks that have control
- concat all 3
- unset all temp field and risks controls

*query is big, but a risk might not have control, a control might not have risk, so its like 3 matches of risks to controls

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6228b275c2de7b441c4b49dd)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$set": 
    {"controls-ids": 
      {"$reduce": 
        {"input": "$controls.links.entity.valueKey",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {"$concatArrays": ["$$value", "$$this"]}}}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"rnc-ids": {"$setDifference": ["$risks._id", "$controls-ids"]},
      "cnr-ids": {"$setDifference": ["$controls-ids", "$risks._id"]}}},
  {"$unset": ["controls-ids"]},
  {"$set": 
    {"cnr": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": 
          {"$filter": 
            {"input": "$controls",
              "cond": 
              {"$eq": 
                [{"$setDifference": 
                    ["$$this.links.entity.valueKey", "$cnr-ids"]},
                  []]}}},
          "in": {"controls": "$$c"},
          "as": "c"}},
      "rnc": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": 
          {"$filter": 
            {"input": "$risks", "cond": {"$in": ["$$this._id", "$rnc-ids"]}}},
          "in": {"$mergeObjects": ["$$r", {"controls": []}]},
          "as": "r"}},
      "rc": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": 
          {"$filter": 
            {"input": "$risks",
              "cond": {"$not": [{"$in": ["$$this._id", "$rnc-ids"]}]}}},
          "in": 
          {"$mergeObjects": 
            ["$$r",
              {"controls": 
                {"$filter": 
                  {"input": "$controls",
                    "cond": {"$in": ["$$r._id", "$$c.links.entity.valueKey"]},
                    "as": "c"}}}]},
          "as": "r"}}}},
  {"$set": {"riskControls": {"$concatArrays": ["$rc", "$rnc", "$cnr"]}}},
  {"$unset": 
    ["controls-ids", "rnc-ids", "cnr-ids", "cnr", "rnc", "rc", "risks",
      "controls"]}])
```

Comment: Thanks @Takis for the help. It works fine for most of the scenarios except one.
The case when it is not working is - when I have a risk with out any control, the "riskControls" field has that risk object populated twice. Example - https://mongoplayground.net/p/zG1EfSc2Spy
In this example "7777-risk2" came twice in riskControls

Comment: i updated the answer and works i think now, because query was a bit complicated and nested arrays etc, if you can, test it before using it.

Comment: thanks, that worked.